# Issues with storm execution in single node

Tags: apache-storm

We have the Storm configured in a single node development server with most of the configurations set to default (not local mode).
Having storm nimbus, supervisor and workers running in that single node only and UI also configured.

AFAIK parallelism and configuration differs from topology to topology.
I think finding the right parallelism and configuration is by trial and error method only.

So, to find the best parallelism we have started testing our Storm topology with various configurations in a single node.

Strangely the results are unexpected:

Our topology processes stream of xml files from HDFS directory.
Having a single spout (Parallelism always 1) and four bolts.

- Single worker

Whatever the topology parallelism we get the almost same performance results (the rate of data processed)

- Multiple workers

Whatever the topology parallelism we get the similar performance as of single worker until sometime (most of the cases it is 10 minutes).

But after that complete topology gets restarted without any error traces.

We had observed that Whatever data processed in 20 minutes with single worker took 90 minutes with 5 workers having the same parallelism.
Also Topology had restarted 7 times with 5 workers.
And CPU usage is relatively high.
(Someone else also had faced this topology restart issue http://search-hadoop.com/m/LrAq5ZWeaU but no answer)

After testing many configurations we found that single worker with less no of parallelism (each bolt with 2 or 3 instances) works better than high parallelism or more no of workers.

Ideally the performance of Storm topology should be better with more no workers/ parallelism.

Apparently this rule is not holding good here.

why can't we set more than a single worker in a single node?

What are the maximum no of workers can be run in a single node?

What are the Storm configurations changes that are need to scale the performance? (I have tried nimbus.childopts and worker.childopts)

Comment: what is the configuration of machine on which you are testing Storm? And are you getting the same error for which you have given the link?

Comment: I don't understand your point. Of course you can define more than 1 worker in a node (a storm hardware). I use 2 or more workers per node (if one worker dies, there is still one left, so I try to avoid "dead" hardware in a storm cluster as there should be one still working left).

Answer (score 0):

If your CPU usage is high on the one node then you're not going to get any better performance as you increase parallelism.  If you do increase parallelism, there will just be greater contention for a constant number of CPU cycles. Not knowing any more about your specific topology, I can only suggest that you look for ways to reduce the CPU usage across your bolts and spouts.  Only then can you would it make sense to add more bolt and spout instances.

Comment: Average CPU Usage is less than 40% only . Please find below SAR command output. 12:30:01 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:40:01 PM     all      0.28      0.00      0.24      0.02      0.00     99.46
12:50:01 PM     all     30.75      0.00      7.37      0.36      0.00     61.52
01:00:01 PM     all     22.33      0.00      6.69      0.23      0.00     70.76